# How to know if any IO Thread is available in windbg?

Tags: windows, threadpool, windbg

I have a legacy application that I am trying to debug which schedules a background task like this:

```
err = QueueUserWorkItem(
                         Foo,
                         NULL,
                         WT_EXECUTEINIOTHREAD);
```

I can see that my function Foo is never executed (i put a breakpoint on the function and it is never hit). So i thought lets see if we have any IO thread avaialble for the function ever or not. But sadly i dont know how to list such threads in windbg. Can anyone help me here please. I am doing this debugging in user mode.

Comment: What OS is it? You can't use `WT_EXECUTEINIOTHREAD` from Vista/Server 2008 upwards.

Comment: You can list all threads using `~* kb`, this will give the call stack for all threads

Comment: What is the alternative? I am using Windows 7

Comment: @EdChum: Yeah but any particular way of deciphering whcih one is a IO Thread that can possibly execute foo?

Comment: I/O worker threads were removed starting with Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008. you may try WT_EXECUTEINPERSISTENTTHREAD or WT_EXECUTELONGFUNCTION

Answer (score 0):

Load sos: `.loadby sos clr` or `.loadby sos mscorwks`

Dump the threads: `!Threads`

Pick an interesting thread: `~<thread number>s` (eg: `~13s`) Then show the stack: `!DumpStack`

You could also try `!EEStack` to show all the threads (can be information overload).